# Adding the Omdb Api using fetch?

Tags: javascript, database, angular, fetch

I am trying to use the OMDB api using fetch and I see in network that my database is working.
However it doesn't show on my Angular 6 page.
What am I missing in this code?

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    return fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=9fa6058b'); 
  } 
}
```

and this

```
import { DataService } from './../data.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-list',
  templateUrl: './movie-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-list.component.css']
})
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit {

  movies = [
    {Title: 'Harry Potter'},
    {Title: 'Space Jam'}
  ]

  constructor(private data:DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=9fa6058b')
    //   .then(response => response.json())
    //   .then( res => this.movies = res);

    this.data.getData()
      .then((response) => {response.json()
      .then((data)=> {this.data = data;
      });
    });
  }
```

and this

```
<p>
  movie-list works!
</p>

<div class="card">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let movie of movies">
      <h2>{{movie.Title}}</h2>
      <h3>{{movie.Plot}}</h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this is what I get ... see picture below.

[image]

What can I do to see the title and plot from the database??

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `response.json()` has to go with the `fetch`

```js
getData() {
  return fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=9fa6058b')
    .then((response) => {
      response.json()
    });
}

this.data.getData().then((data) => {
  this.data = data;
});
```

Also the response is an object so you need to push the object to an array to use `*ngFor`

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgfhhc)

Comment: Now {this.data = data} is not working !! Whats wrong?

Comment: What if I change the api to 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=game&apikey=9fa6058b' with a search work? How should I change the function?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added the fetched data to your array of movies.

```
movies = [
{Title: 'Harry Potter'},
{Title: 'Space Jam'}]
```

This is why you are not seeing the desired data.

Edit: You could try and do this:

```
    let movies = [];

    function doFetch() {
        fetch('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=9fa6058b', {
            method: "get"
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (text) {
            let json = JSON.parse(text);
            let data = { Title: json.Title, Plot: json.Plot }
            movies.push(data);
        });
    }

    doFetch();
```

This way you will populate your array with the data to display it later.

Comment: How do I do so?